# How to keep My Application（record screen）alive when back to background in android phone？

Tags: android, record, recycle

I write a record screen applicatioin，when I press the start button，
begin to record screen and
call moveTaskToBack(true);

when I don't do heavy task ，the record screen work ok，
when I do some heavy task，the record screen application recycle by android，

what can I do to keep my record screen Application alive when I do heavy task
in the foreground？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to block the Android recycling mechanism. If the system needs resources, it will kill the components of the non-foreground processes.

What you can do is move the work to a `Service` and use as few resources as possible. Then launch this `Service` as a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) to ensure it will not be first in line for recycling.

But you can never be 100% sure it will not be killed, because this depends on many factors, such as device specs and system code modifications (which are very common on Android devices.